# Query regarding ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting

I want to plot [list line plot] sin[i] as a function of i, where i is varied from 0 to 2*pi in steps of 0.1. Now, how can I get the plot within 2*pi, whereas the actual plot gives from 0 to 62.8 i.e [10*2*pi]

```
ListLinePlot[Table[Sin[i], {i, 0, 2 *Pi, 0.1}]]
```

Comment: `ListLinePlot[Table[{i, Sin[i]}, {i, 0, 2*Pi, 0.1}]]`

Comment: `ListLinePlot[Table[Sin[i], {i, 0, 2 *Pi, 0.1}], DataRange->{0, 2 Pi}]` also works.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Maybe that should be `DataRange -> {0, Floor[2 Pi, 0.1]}`.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Indeed, so.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're not seeing what you think you're seeing.  What happens is that `Table[Sin[i], {i, 0, 2*Pi, 0.1}]` generates 63 points.  When you plot them, they are plotted against their integer indexes.  The suggestion by bbgodfrey addresses this by changing the `DataRange`.  The suggestion by Feyre addresses this by specifying the function points instead of just the function range.  I like the latter approach, but I would do it this way:

```
ListLinePlot[{#, Sin[#]} & /@ Range[0, 2 Pi, 0.1]]
```

Although personally, I generally care more about the number of points than the stepsize, so actually I'd be inclined to do it this way:

```
ListLinePlot[{#, Sin[#]} & /@ Subdivide[2 Pi, 62]]
```